# SQL Server- alternates to Filters using NOT IN

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which provides me a count based on multiple conditions.

```
WHERE 
    *Other conditions* 
    AND ((WORKTYPE = 'SS' AND TOT_SUBTYPE IN ('SSSERREN', 'SSERRLT') AND TOT_TASKTYPE = 'CONS') 
         OR ISNULL(TOT_TASKTYPE,'CONS') IN ('CONS','CONSX'))
```

The above statement would filter CONS,CONSX AND NULL for all except 'WORKTYPE = 'SS' AND TOT_SUBTYPE IN ('SSSERREN','SSERRLT') ' and it would filter just 'CONS'

My issue is its providing me an extra line in my output including TOT_TASKTYPE = 'CONSX' when Worktype =SS and TOT_TASKTYPE = SSSERREN AND SSERRLT.

I tried to modify the query as given below:

```
    ((WORKTYPE = 'SS' AND TOT_SUBTYPE IN ('SSSERREN','SSERRLT') and 
    TOT_TASKTYPE = 'CONS')                                          
     OR 
    (WORKTYPE NOT IN ('SS'))
    AND
    ISNULL(TOT_TASKTYPE,'CONS') IN ('CONS','CONSX'))
```

This query provided me correct ones for the condition mentioned earlier, but it removed the other line items from my output with Worktype 'SS'.

I further changed my query to include not in both WORKTYPE and TOT_SUBTYPE, but its taking a lot of time to execute. I'm not sure if this would give me the desired output.

```
    ((WORKTYPE = 'SS' AND TOT_SUBTYPE IN ('SSSERREN','SSERRLT') and 
    TOT_TASKTYPE = 'CONS')                                          
    OR 
   (WORKTYPE NOT IN ('SS') AND TOT_SUBTYPE NOT IN ('SSSERREN','SSERRLT')
    AND
    ISNULL(TOT_TASKTYPE,'CONS') IN ('CONS','CONSX'))
```

Is there any other way to modify the code instead of using "NOT IN" resolve my issue?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Specifically, this sentence *My issue is its providing me an extra line in my output including TOT_TASKTYPE = 'CONSX' when Worktype =SS and TOT_TASKTYPE = SSSERREN AND SSERRLT.* How can `TOT_TASKTYPE` be CONSX **and** SSSERREN **and** SSERRLT? Is this a comma separated string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to modify the code instead of using `NOT IN`

I recommend using `not exists` over `in`

The majority of the time I have found `not exists` has better performance.